# Spawn process and redirect current bash script's output to it

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

How can I spawn a new background process from a bash script and redirect the current script's stdout/stderr to that process's stdin using fd redirection? I know of a few ways to accomplish the same effect, such as  using a named pipe or a temporary file, using coprocs, or running the whole script in a subshell and redirecting the ouptut of that to the other process, but I am looking for a simple one line IO redirection from within the script, in the same way I can do this: `exec 2>&1`. Basically, I want to do something like this (the way the process is spawned can be changed of course):

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --text-info & # The process to receive this script's output
# Do something to redirect this shell's stdout 
# to the background process's stdin
echo "something" # This should be read by the background process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this using process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Redirect stdout/stderr of current process to stdin of spawned process
# The >() syntax evaluates to a file descriptor that is connected
# to the new process's stdin
exec &> >(zenity --text-info)
```